# Convergence/ divergence of a series

Tags: calculus

Hi may i ask how to do this convergence question.
$$
\sum_n \frac{2^n}{8^{n+2}}-\frac{1}{2n}.
$$
I tried using the comparison test and root teat but i could not get the answer.

Comment: Show that $\sum{2^n\over 8^{n+2}}$ converges. If your sum converged, it would then follow that the harmonic series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Change signs (multiply by $-1$). It makes no difference to the convergence but makes things look nicer. Then use **Limit Comparison** with the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Or else consider the partial sums
$$\sum_1^N \left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{2^n}{8^{n+2}}\right).\tag{1}$$
The partial sums $\sum_1^N \frac{1}{2n}$ are unbounded, while the partial sums 
$\sum_1^N\frac{2^n}{8^{n+2}}$ are bounded, so the partial sums (1) are unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sum_n \frac{2^n}{8^{n+2}}-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac1{8^2}\sum_n\left(\frac14\right)^n-\frac12\sum_n\frac1n$$

The first part is an infinte [Geometric Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) with common ratio being $\frac14<1$, hence convergent

Comment: Yeah i managed to reach here, but the left hand side is convergent while the right hand side is divergent.

Comment: @yswong, so we have convergent $-$ divergent, which must be divergent for if  convergent$-$ divergent$=$convergent, then $??$